# Sql Query OrderBy issue

Tags: sql-server

when i try to run the following query

```
DECLARE @QUERY1 VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @QUERY1=(SELECT [ResponsibleEngineerID],[ResponsibleEngineer],DocType
FROM tblResponsibleEngineer 
WHERE ResponsibleEngineer NOT IN ('(Select a Responsible Engineer...)')
ORDER BY [ResponsibleEngineer] ASC
)
EXEC(@QUERY1)
```

i get the error

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR
>   XML is also specified.

why this error occurs? and i need to write the sql query exactly in above format.like assign the query to a variable and then execute

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  DECLARE @QUERY1 VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @QUERY1='SELECT [ResponsibleEngineerID],[ResponsibleEngineer],DocType
    FROM tblResponsibleEngineer 
    WHERE REPLACE(Responsible Engineer,'''','''''') NOT IN (Select a REPLACE(Responsible   Engineer,'''','''''')...)
    ORDER BY [ResponsibleEngineer] ASC'

    EXEC(@QUERY1)
```

Comment: i can not use this query coz there are ResponsibleEngineers with names like Davo'rely(with single quote)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the *result* of the query to @QUERY1, not the actual query text.

As far as I understand, this is what you want;

```
DECLARE @QUERY1 VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @QUERY1='SELECT [ResponsibleEngineerID],[ResponsibleEngineer],DocType
FROM tblResponsibleEngineer 
WHERE ResponsibleEngineer NOT IN (Select a Responsible Engineer...)
ORDER BY [ResponsibleEngineer] ASC'

EXEC(@QUERY1)
```

Comment: i can not use this query coz there are ResponsibleEngineers with names like Davo'rely(with single quote).i need to write a Insert statement in the same way.so can not ignore single quote

Comment: @chamara If the `Select a Responsible Engineer...` part is actually a select query and does not contain `Davo'rely` as text, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the query to a variable then executing it - you're executing the query and attempting to assign the *result* of that query to a variable.

Had your query not contained an illegal expression for a subquery, you'd have received an error about the subquery returning multiple columns.

Declare variable:

```
DECLARE @QUERY1 VARCHAR(MAX)
```

Assign result of a query to a variable:

```
SET @QUERY1=(SELECT [ResponsibleEngineerID],[ResponsibleEngineer],DocType
FROM tblResponsibleEngineer 
WHERE ResponsibleEngineer NOT IN ('(Select a Responsible Engineer...)')
ORDER BY [ResponsibleEngineer] ASC
)
```

What you probably intended:

```
DECLARE @QUERY1 VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @QUERY1='SELECT [ResponsibleEngineerID],[ResponsibleEngineer],DocType
FROM tblResponsibleEngineer 
WHERE ResponsibleEngineer NOT IN (''(Select a Responsible Engineer...)'')
ORDER BY [ResponsibleEngineer] ASC'

EXEC(@QUERY1)
```

(Note that I've doubled the quotes inside the string now)

Comment: i can not use this query coz there are ResponsibleEngineers with names like Davo'rely(with single quote).i need to write a Insert statement in the same way.so can not ignore single quote

Comment: @chamara - I don't understand your comment

Comment: if there are text with single quotes for select and insert this kind of query doesn't work wright?

Comment: @chamara - if your query is something entirely unlike what you've shown in your question, it may or may not work - we're not mind readers.